# How to negate perl regex with lookbehind?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I have this text (`file.txt`) to inspect:

```
_abcd
_efgh
#, _1
```

Now I want to match only words with underscore but that are not preceded with hash `#`. To mach all, I can do

```
$perl -nle 'print $1 if /(_\w+)/' file.txt
```

But I dont want to match the hash, so I will try the lookbehind:

```
$ perl -nle 'print $1 if /(?<!#.+)(_\w+)/' file.txt

Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<!#.+)(_\w+)/ at -e line 1.
```

1. How to implement variable length lookbehind in perl?

For the second, I will try to do lookahead:

```
$ perl -nle 'print $1 if /(?!#.+)(_\w+)/' file.txt
```

which will again match all, including the `#` line, which I do not want.

2. How to match all, except the `#` line (in other words, how to negate regex)?

Comment: Try `/#.+(*SKIP)(*F)|\b_\w+/`

Comment: Or maybe`^(?!.*#).*(_\w+)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you please explain? Have no idea what `(*SKIP)` or `(*F)` means, because it solved the issue, but I do not know this regex variables

Comment: @JvdV, That fails for `_foo  # bar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
/#.+(*SKIP)(*F)|_\w+/
```

Or, to match `_` at the word boundary:

```
/#.+(*SKIP)(*F)|\b_\w+/
```

The pattern matches

- `#.+(*SKIP)(*F)` - `#` and any 1 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then the match is skipped, omitted, discarded and the next  match is searched for from the place where the match was skipped
- `|` - or
- `_\w+` - a `_` and then any 1 or more word chars.

Comment: so the "discarding" is made via `(*SKIP)`, and `(*F)` is for "continue from that point"? or what does `(*F)` do?

Comment: @milanHrabos `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` works like this, skips the text matched and `(*F)` / `(*FAIL)` causes an immediate fail.

Comment: It's all in [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: @milanHrabos Also, `(*F)` / `(*FAIL)` can be replaced with `(?!)`, it also causes a failure at the place where it is used.

Answer (score 3):

The following will do:

```
/^[^#]*(_\w+)/
```